# How to clear AWS Cloudfront-cache for API Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

for development I use API Gateway to access lambda functions.

There was a 500 Error in a lambda and cloudfront seems to cache it, as after that I constantly receive that in the request header:

```
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

... combined with a 401 error.

I did not setup cloudfront by my own. And I don't find any cloudfront instances. The API URLs I access directly (`someid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod`).

And I see in cloudwatch logs, my lambda is not called again - it realy seems to use the cached information. And it is a POST request.

Is there a way to invalidate that cached state?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable caching in AWS API Gateway it creates a CloudFront distribution behind the scenes to manage your API cache. You need to [go into the API Gateway UI to clear the cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html).

> Flush the API stage cache in API Gateway
> When API caching is enabled, you can flush your API stage's cache to ensure that your API's clients get the most recent responses from your integration endpoints.
>
> To flush the API stage cache, you choose the **Flush entire cache** button under the **Cache Settings** section in the **Settings** tab in a stage editor of the API Gateway console.

Comment: Hmm, but I did not enable that API cache. But it is cached in a cloudfront somewhere.

Comment: And it is a POST request. Means the API cache you mentioned should have no effect anyway.

Comment: When you enable caching for a stage, only GET methods have caching enabled by default. This helps to ensure the safety and availability of your API. You can enable caching for other methods by overriding method settings.

Comment: I did find a workaround, but no explanation: As I use cognito and JWT to get access to this ressource, I logout and logedin again. Means it uses a new JWT token then. And it looks like it is not using this error again.

I have the feeling, it cached for the token a 401 caused by the formal 500.